# Changing the grid setup, but what about the list view?

Tags: theme, product-list, grid-layout

I want to use a modified version of the Mobile Shoppe theme for one of our magento stores. I edited the `app/design/frontend/default/mobileshoppe2/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` file. In this file most code for displaying products is used twice, once for the grid, once for the list view. Whether grid or list is used is based on the following code:

```
<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
```

We use grid view for all sites. Can I ignore the list view entirely, leave the code as it is? I can't think of a situation where it is used, but maybe it is used somewhere that I don't know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore the list completely. In fact it stands to reason to use one or another, not both (Grid is meant for stuff you buy because of visual appeal (such as clothes or furniture), List is for technical stuff or products that require additional information before purchasing decision). Having both of them might be confusing and distract customer from purchase flow.

As was mentioned by @user6451 you should head to

> System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog

and make sure that your display only the list you need. Also make sure that mode switcher is correctly implemented (it should disappear once single display mode is selected). It can be found here:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

If there's something like that:

```
<?php if( $this->isEnabledViewSwitcher() ): ?>
```

You're probably good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are, right. This is the piece of code. 
If you want to disable any view you can do it via admin.

> System > Configuration > Catalog>catalog>Frontend Grid Only

And it will be done.